# SonataAdminBundle field sonata_type_model without new button

Tags: button, symfony, admin, field, sonata-admin

I'm using the sonata_type_model of the SonataAdminBundle.

I get the dropdown of the other model like I want to. But there is also a "New" Button to create the referenced model. Is it possible to remove this button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, my bad.

The new button is the part that makes this field type special. To just get a choices field all one has to do is choose "null" as type and it creates a choices field.

Answer (score 5):

In case you're using the `query` option too, you can't switch to the choices field, since the option is not available.

Setting `btn_add` to `false` will do it.

E.g.

```php
->add('myEntity', 'sonata_type_model',
    array('query' => $this->modelManager->getEntityManager('Acme\HelloBundle\Entity\MyEntity')->createQueryBuilder('m')
        ->select(array('m'))
        ->from('AcmeHelloBundle:MyEntity', 'm')
        ->where('m.type = ' . MyEntity::PIZZA),
        "btn_add" => false
    ))
```